# Why Is h1's height rounded down, ignoring its actual line-height? (With Codepen)

Tags: sass, css, rounding-error

When an `h1` element has a line-height set on it and no other height, no matter whether the `line-height` is set in rems or pixels, the calculated height of the element is rounded down. Checked in Chrome and Firefox.

Why is this?

In both cases, I would expect the `h1`'s height to be the same as its `line-height`, however the element's height is rounded down to 20px. Setting an explicit height the same as the line-height visibly shows a change in height, so it isn't an issue with the inspector's output.

[Codepen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKmtg)

```
<header>
  <h1 class="with-rems">Some Text</h1>
</header>
<header>
  <h1 class="with-px">Some Text</h1>
</header>
```

Sass:

```
.with-rems
{
  margin: 0;
  font-size:  1rem;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

.with-px
{
  margin: 0;
  font-size:  16px;
  line-height: 20.799999237060547px;
}
```

Comment: A pixel always needs to be an integer. (would be hard to fill half a pixel with 1 color and the other half with another). As for the rounding down, I suspect is just made to do so.

Comment: @dwana The first example uses rems and as I mention in the question, using a fractional value explicitly causes a visible height change. Also, fractional values for pixels have been supported for a long time: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#length-units

Comment: @cimmanon How is this question a duplicate. It asks about line-height in relation to height. The question you've marked as a duplicate talks about percentage related to width.

Comment: a pixel is the smallest possible thing your display can show, so it has to be an integer !A rem has a size of more then 1 pixel let's say 16, and you can do 16*1.3 (if you need more info search for "subpixel rendering")

Comment: @Pedr Do you honestly think the browser rounds differently when the value in question is on line-height vs any other property?  The linked question is not limited to percentages.

Comment: @cimmanon There's no need to be condescending. Obviously I don't think that. However you are conflating questions and answers. I wasn't looking for an answer or question on browser treatment of height/width, but in its treatment of height when height is defined by line-height. Although the question you marked as a duplicate has an answer that explains this one, the intention of the question is completely different. It's like closing 'Why does rain fall downwards?' because it is a dupe of 'how does the atmosphere remain in place?' The answer to both is gravity but they are different questions.